# Nuget package for ILMerged dll

Tags: nuget, ilmerge

I would like to package up an ILMerge'd dll using Nuget.

Currently I can do this however the package also includes the dlls that I've just merged and also installs some other nuget package dependencies that I have.

What I would like would be a way of specifying in the nuspec file that it should only include my merged dll, and that it should not add references to the nuget dependencies so effectively when a user installs this package they will get a single dll reference in their project and no additional nuget dependencies.

Is this possible to define within the nuspec? or is there a better approach to achieve this?

Comment: It would help if you'd explain how you are building your NuGet package. Assuming you have a handwritten .nuspec file this change would be trivial as the .nuspec file explicitly calls out which files get added to the package.

Answer (score 2):

Well, while packaging the DLL(s), make sure you do not have the dependent references in the lib. Also, make sure in the nuspec file, there are no references added.

Directory Structure:

```
My_Package
| - lib
    | - [Required Dll's]
| - My_Package.nuspec
```

Edit the nuspec file and remove all references:

```
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="DLLDependency" version="1.0" />
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release\mydll.dll" target="lib" />
    <file src="bin\Release\mydll.pdb" target="lib" />
  </files>
</package>
```